# Unity 3D - Get Screen.width from other class failed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 classes in Unity 3D.

1st class is linked with a scene.

```
public class MyScene : MonoBehaviour {
  private Rect frame1Rect;
  public Texture storyFrame1;

  void Start() {
    frame1Rect = new Rect(0, 0, storyFrame1.width * UIManager.SW, storyFrame1.height * UIManager.SH);
  }
}
```

and an Utility class:

```
public class UIManager {
    public static float SW {
        get { return Screen.width / 1080; }
    }
    public static float SH {
        get { return Screen.height / 1920; }
    }
}
```

The `Rect` becomes `(0, 0, 0, 0)`

If I replace the `frame1Rect` line with:

```
frame1Rect = new Rect(0, 0, storyFrame1.width * Screen.width / 1080, Screen.height * storyFrame1.height / 1920);
```

It works again. What is the reason of unable to obtain the value of `SW` from `UIManager` ?

Comment: What are the value of `storyFrame1.width` and `Screen.width` for example?

Comment: `Screen.width` is Unity 3D's built-in property, represents the screen width of device. For a portrait device with full HD resolution, it has 1080 width. `storyFrame1.width` is the width of the texture. For example, 320 width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet you you're getting integer division here.

[`Screen.width`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html) (and `height`) is an `int`. Same with [`Texture.width`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-width.html).

In your `UIManager.SW` property, you have this expression:

```
return Screen.width / 1080;
```

Now, most likely `Screen.width` is in or around 1080ish. With integer division, that will truncate and before converting it to a `float` to return. For example, if `Screen.width` is `540`, you won't return `0.5`, you'll return `0`. If `Screen.width` is `1,620`, you won't return `1.5`, you'll return `1`.

In your non-UIManager code, you have this expression instead:

```
storyFrame1.width * Screen.width / 1080
```

This is still using integer division, but the initial multiplication of `storyFrame1.width * Screen.width` will create a very large value (say `291600 / 1080`) which will still truncate but provide a seemingly correct value of `270`.

To fix it, you'll want to cast your integer values to `float` before dividing:

```
public class UIManager {
    public static float SW {
        get { return ((float)Screen.width) / 1080; }
    }
    public static float SH {
        get { return ((float)Screen.height) / 1920; }
    }
}
```

<s>Also, as an aside, are you sure your *width* value should be dividing by `1080` or should it be `1920`? (Similarly for height. It looks like your values may be flipped, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.)</s> EDIT: I see you're using portrait orientation, nevermind.

Comment: That was my first thought also but he said `Screen.width` as 1080 and `storyFrame1.width` as `320`. So we have `320 * 1080 / 1080` and we get `320` as a result not `0`.

Comment: @SonerGönül: This will only work _if_ `Screen.width` is reporting as a _full_ 1080. But if it's less (say to accommodate chrome, or running in an emulator with lower resolution, or a smaller device) even by 1 pixel so reporting as 1079 then there will be a problem.  In the in-line code without `UIManager`, it will evaluate as `(320 * 1079) / 1080` which will result in `319`. In the `UIManager.SW` code, it will evaluate as `320 * (1079 / 1080)` which will result in `0`. I _suspect_ Raptor is reporting an _expected_ size, but it's not the _actual_ size being used in his test case.